# Storage and fast access to huge picture data

Tags: database, image, image-processing, concurrency, blob

I am currently involved in designing a face matching system and we have to deal with more than 3 Million images. But I have a vague idea about how to store those images and access them fast enough to achieve the highest possible performance.

**MySQL Server:**

This is easy because I am familiar with it. But doubt that the performance would be not acceptable. Of course I have not tried it. As I have read, there is a new datatype called *filestream* where we can store images and access them faster. Another option is, I can store the file path in the database and access the image after querying for the image path.

**Other**
I also have an idea for `NoSQL` solution. I have no experience in it. As found MongoDB is a good option for `NoSQL` the most popular and can be used as a file structure as well.

I am thinking of using good amount of *concurrency*, which should increase the higher concurrent data access as well.

Can somebody give me a heads up on this issue and the the best database technology that is available.

**Edit:**
UseCase: User gives a image of a person as a input and the system has to provide with a most possible set of matched of the face images in the database.

I thought about process the images separately as the number or cores(X) the images are queued in different queues which are going to be used by the application for image processing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is far to vague.  Please give the use-cases that will apply, describing frequency of access, the queries being performed, the processing being performed, etc, etc...

Comment: @Dems is the edit sufficient. This is basically what happens. I have to think about it, if I have to give you more details. Because I we are still not there yet

Comment: Your use-case suggests that you will load and compare every image with the user's supplied image.  That is not what a DB is for.  If you can PRE-process the images, and generate searchable meta-data for each image, then you are on to something for a DB.

Comment: @Dems yes, I get you. I thought like having the pictures processed every time a search is done. If metadata is the case to hold data in the database. Then we can use SQL Server. Correct me if I m wrong